# Regex to match repeating 3 digit groups that aren't made up of 3 identical digits

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match repeating 3 digit groups that appear in a UK phone number. I already can get the match when the 3 digits are identical in the groups with this pattern:
`r'(\d)\1{2}'`

E.g. when input is "07119777777" I get two matches:

```
<re.Match object; span=(5, 8), match='777'>
<re.Match object; span=(8, 11), match='777'>
```

However when input is something like "07123123123" I get no matches as the digits inside the 3 digit group are different. **Is there a regex pattern to identify these as matches?**

Comment: Does this work `(\d{3})\1+`?

Comment: Almost! It does find matches where the digits aren't identical e.g. for "07590759759" match becomes  "759759" but the "759" after the 0 is not found as a match. Also, trying to get each 3 digit group as seperate matches e.g. "759" and "759" not "759759".

Comment: Would have been nice to express those as requirements up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
str = "07590759759"
m = re.search(r'(\d{3}).*?(\1).*?(\1)', str)
print(m.groups())
```

Output:

```
('759', '759', '759')
```

**[Update]**
Answering your additional question, I suppose it is not possible with
regex only. (It may be, but I cannot figure out so far.)
Here is an approach:

```
str = "07590759759012759"
m = re.search(r'(\d{3})((?:.*?\1)+)', str)
m1, m2 = m.groups()                     # m1: first match, m2: remaining sequence of matches
m3 = re.findall(m1, m2)                 # extract multiple m1's out of m2
print([m1] + m3)                        # concatenate them as a list
```

Output:

```
['075', '075']
```

The output may not be what you expect because the code above outputs
*two or more* repetitions.
If you want to limit up to three or more repetitions, modify the `re.search()`
line as:

```
m = re.search(r'(\d{3})((?:.*?\1){2,})', str)
```

Then the output will be:

```
['759', '759', '759', '759']
```

Comment: Yes that achieves what I’m looking for pretty much! Thank you very much. Only thing I can think of is that this is specifically looking for 3 repeats like you provided. Wonder if there is a way to search for any number of repeats of if you would just have to call a similar function with a different amount “.*?(/1)” in the pattern?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer with an additional code. I hope it will meet your requirement. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am very new to regex and was struggling with figuring this out using the documentation.